# Rewriting CSS and image URLs

Tags: html, mod-rewrite

I've got this code to remove .html

```
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html

 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.html
```

Going to posts.html works, but posts does not display CSS or images, help?